# SolrCore Initialization Failures - error accessing managed-schema config

Tags: solr

I ran Sitecore "Getting Started template" and got SolrCore Initialization Failures.

> ```
> sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web_shard1_replica_n1: 
> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
> Could not load conf for core sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web_shard1_replica_n1: 
> Error attempting to access /configs/sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web_config/managed-schema
> ```

[image]

Comment: Are you using this walkthrough for the "Getting Started Template"? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html

Comment: yes i am using "Getting Started Template"

Comment: Is there something you need to run as an administrator? Does this file exist? `/configs/sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web_config/managed-schema`

Comment: I am running ./up.ps1 in Windows powershell with administrator privilages...

Answer (score 0):

do NOT put double quotes in :)  ""

[image]